# preg_replace: replacing using %

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the function preg_replace but I cannot figure out how to make it work, the function just doesn't seem to work for me.

What I'm trying to do is to convert a string into a link if any word contains the % (percentage) character.

For instance if I have the string "go to %mysite", I'd like to convert the mysite word into a link.
I tried the following...

```
$data = "go to %mysite";
$result = preg_replace('/(^|[\s\.\,\:\;]+)%([A-Za-z0-9]{1,64})/e', 
          '\\1%<a href=#>\\2</a>', $data);
```

...but it doesn't work.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Juan

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work"? It doesn't change the input at all? It changes the input incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks Asher for your reply. 
I didn't manage to debug this code but what happens when I add a % on the $data variable, the code just stops at the preg_replace function. I also tried to add a try catch but the same thing happens, the code just stops at the preg_replace
Any idea? is there any other way I could achieve the same thing?
Juan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is `e` modifier which evaluates the replacement as php code and fails with fatal error

---

Removing `e` attribute will output `go to %<a href=#>mysite</a>` and if it is desired result, you don't have to change anything else.

But I think that `preg_replace_callback` is what you really need, ie:

```
function createLinks($matches)
{
    switch($matches[2])
    {
        case 'mysite':
            $url = 'http://mysite.com/';
            break;
        case 'google':
            $url = 'http://www.google.com/';
            break;
    }

    return "{$matches[1]}%<a href=\"{$url}\">{$matches[2]}</a>";
}

$data = "go to %mysite or visit %google";
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(^|[\s\.\,\:\;]+)%([A-Za-z0-9]{1,64})/',
    'createLinks',
    $data
);
```

that will result in `go to %<a href="http://mysite.com/">mysite</a> or visit %<a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a>`

Comment: Hi dev-null-dweller, thank you for your answer. Do you know how I can fix this issue? Do I have to use the e modifier?
Thanks
Juan

Comment: Thanks dev-null-dweller, this is exactly what I'm aiming for. I'll give it a try. Thanks again