# Replacing string coming from the DB with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am using Smarty for my template engine.

But I have an issue that is driving me crazy, so please provide a concrete example if you have the solution.

I have some HTML saved in the mySQL DB. When I get it I want to replace `{$foo}` with the correct value of the variable.

I am trying to do this because I have a multi-language website. So lets assume that this is the code given into the variable `$content` coming from the DB:

```
$content = <div id="help">{$lang['helpmeout'}</div>
            <div id="hello">{$lang['hello']}</div>
```

Now assuming that the content above is coming from the DB and that is stored into the $content variable, how do I say to smarty to catch the variables inside the brackets `{}` and to treat them as normal PHP code? I cannot really get it working.

Nobody seems to have a working solution for this.

Please help

Comment: Do you really have to store PHP code into database ? It is discouraged to store php into database, people generally prefer creating php files and require it depending on context.

Comment: Just to be sure: to interpret them as PHP variables or Smarty variables?

Comment: So you would have to take the string, add some markup and evaluate it as php code. You would also have to consider scope of variables, possibility of inserting malicious code etc, so instead of trying to do so, please use different approach, ie. some kind of placeholders like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398508/preg-replace-replacing-using/2398580#2398580

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Selecting HTML from the DB and apply changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057124/php-selecting-html-from-the-db-and-apply-changes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Smarty works. Consider this snippet to parse the php variables:

```
$lang = array('helpmeout' => 'helpMeOut', 'hello' => 'hi');
$content = '<div id="help">{$lang[\'helpmeout\']}</div>
<div id="hello">{$lang[\'hello\']}</div>';
eval('$c = "'.str_replace('"', '\"', $content).'";');
echo $c;
```

The point here is that evaluating `$c = "$content"` (scaping ") will parse the php variables.

I hope that helps.

Comment: eval can be dangereous. RTM before deciding to use it http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

Smarty 3 knows the [string resource](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl). If you need to disable certain Smarty features for this, have a look at [Smarty Security](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security).